# How to control Time zone formatting in System.Xml.Serialization or during application execution?

Tags: c#, datetime, xml-serialization, timezone

I'm developing a C# .Net Application that is executing on a system located in the Central Time Zone. The application gets information from a third party using an API they provide. I have used the WSDL to produce the code that my application access the API with...their reporting API allows you to define a start date and end date for the report. These are C# DateTime fields and XSD:dateTime. Now when I set the start date and end dates and allow the API to create the SOAP messages the dates don't always include a Time Zone unless I set the date fields using the ToLocalTime method; however, the method will create the DateTime fields in the Central Time Zone (CST) but I need to have it create these fields in the Pacific Time Zone (PST). If I set my machine time to PST all is good...but of course that causes other time issues. What methods can I use to control the formatting of the DateTime? Alternatively, is there a application setting that can be set in C# that allows timezone control?

Comment: Up vote for the ToLocalTime method hack for getting the timezone to be serialized into the SOAP message.  Saved my day... more like week.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to achieve this by using [System.TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). For example:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myLocalTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(“Pacific Standard Time”));
```

Comment: Tried variations of this the problem occurs when having to make the assignment to the date time field for the class generated by the WSDL --- I've had to log SOAP messages to see what is sent...the only case where the timezone is there is when using the ToLocalTime method --- which uses the Timezone of the machine the application is executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options. Obviously what you can do will depend on how the target system handle the date times it receives.

1- Convert the datetime to the target timezone and send the request without timezone info. This would assume that the target system will accept a datetime that does not have timezone info as being in the PST timezone.

2- Change to using [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx). This will allow you to explicitly specify the timezone offset and will be serialized with the timezone info you specified.

If possible I would go for option 2.

Comment: I also tried the DateTimeOffset, which I really preferred...but the WSDL generated class has the data element typed as a DateTime....I never could get variations of using the DateTimeOffset to have the Timezone....are you suggesting I modify the class generated by the WSDL?

Comment: @Beal, I think you will need to change the generated classes, I realise this is terrible practice and personally I would try avoid it. But at least give it a try to see if it works, then if we are on the right track we can see if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Tried modifying the generated class...this causes an error with the Provider (Yahoo EWS)...back trying to figure out another alternative....